# Membase or Redis for memory caching system

Tags: memory, redis, distributed-caching, membase

I have planned to use membase or redis for memmory caching system in my applications.
The thing i have mush confusion about which is best for persistence caching system??
can you peoples suggest which is best of each among them whats the reason.
Also comparison and benchmark between redis and membase.

Comment: I have used redis and did not have any problems with it.. There's a benchmark here: http://www.ruturaj.net/redis-memcached-tokyo-tyrant-mysql-comparison but it might be obsolete by now..

Answer (score 3):

I have posted an answer to a similar Membase / Redis comparison question on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071588/what-is-the-major-difference-between-redis-and-membase/5588242#5588242).

In short, Membase scales better, Redis offers more features, but Membase recently merged with CouchDB and will gain its mapreduce and querying functionality in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered [Infinispan](http://www.infinispan.org)?  Even though it is JVM-based, with its client/server modules you can access/consume Infinispan from pretty much any platform.